# Getting this error while using context API. TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

i have just tried to access a variable from another component using context api and it is throwing weird errors.

Here is my parent component.

```
import React,{createContext,useState} from 'react'

export const CartContext=createContext()    

const CartValue =(props)=>{
    const [cart,setCart]=useState(0)
    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={[cart,setCart]}>
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
        
    )
}

export default CartValue
```

and the below is my child component.

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import CartValue,{CartContext} from './CartValue'


function ChildContext() {
    const [cart,setCart]=useContext(CartContext)
    return (
        <div>
           <h3>{cart}</h3>

        </div>
    )
}

export default ChildContext
```

and the below is the error i am getting.

```
TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

please resolve this issue. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the Context API all you need to do is wrap your component inside  thats it.

below is my solution

```
       <CartValue>
            <ChildContext />
       </CartValue>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `cart` as a value into your `CartContext.Provider` which means your context contains the value of `cart` which seems to be a number defaulting to `0`. But when using your context you treat it as if it is an array that has been returned by a `useState`. This is why you see the error `Object is not iterable`. There is nothing weird about that error. It just means you tried to iterate over something that is not an array or anything iterable at all.

If you want to do it like that you need to put everything returned from your `useState` into the context, not only the state value:

```
const CartValue =(props)=>{
    const cartState = useState(0)

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={cartState}>
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>  
    )
}
```

Comment: then how can i update cartState value without a method?

Comment: @manee You aren't currently updating it in the `CartValue` component so you don't need the method there. You can still update it where you consume the context as you pass the whole array with the value and the updater function into the context.

Comment: i am not getting any output after following this except a blank screen

Comment: it is returning an undefined value .i have checked it by console.log()

Comment: @manee How are your rendering your components? Are you aware that you need to wrap `ChildContext` into `CardValue` to make it work? See this for a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-shannon-nor48?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you did everything in a same file but i did everything in different files.

Comment: @manee Why does that matter? It is just an example for demonstration purposes. It works the same when you have the components in different files and import them where you use it. What is the error in the console when you open your app? I'm afraid to say but you clearly seem to lack a basic understanding of es6 javascript and/or react. Please start with the tutorial first and try to understand it fully before trying it on your own.

Comment: ok sorry for troubling you i will go through this clearly and will do everything slowly thanks for your time @trixn

Comment: @manee I upated the sandbox to show it works the same with different files: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-shannon-nor48?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```js
const [cart,setCart]=useContext(CartContext)
```

to

```js
const cart = useContext(CartContext)
```

The reason being, the value you provided in your `CartContext.Provider value={cart}` is a number, not an array.

Comment: i have seen this in a tutorial and tried. there he said we can send entire state through this context api

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64402020/6220015) for that